# How to connect to Cassandra nodes with different ports?

Tags: python, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-python-driver, cassandra-python-driver

I am trying to connect to cluster nodes having different ports (9042 and 9043), but cannot find ways to do it here:

```
cluster = Cluster(['0.0.0.0','0.0.0.0'],port=9042)
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

As of v3.27 of the DataStax's Python driver for Cassandra, `Cluster`'s `contact_points` parameter seems to accept a tuple of IP and port.

https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/blob/3.27.0/cassandra/cluster.py#L581-L585

> ```
> class Cluster(object):
>     ...
>
>     contact_points = ['127.0.0.1']
>     """
>     The list of contact points to try connecting for cluster discovery. A
>     contact point can be a string (ip or hostname), a tuple (ip/hostname, port) or a
>     :class:`.connection.EndPoint` instance.
> ```

You can do

```
cluster = Cluster(
    contact_points=[
      ('0.0.0.0', 9042),
      ('0.0.0.0', 9043),
    ]
    ...
)
```

and then just leave the `port=` parameter as empty.